# Server error while resetting the CloudKit badge

Tags: ios, reset, badge, cloudkit, server-error

For some weeks now my app is unable to reset the CloudKit badge. I am getting a 'Network Failure' error. It did work before and I have not changed any code. I cannot find anything about changed functionality. Is this a CloudKit bug? Should i file a Radar? Or am I doing something wrong?

Here is the code that I use:

```
public func setBadgeCounter(count:Int) {
    let badgeResetOperation = CKModifyBadgeOperation(badgeValue: count)
    badgeResetOperation.modifyBadgeCompletionBlock = { (error) -> Void in            
        func handleError(error: NSError) -> Void {
            EVLog("Error: could not reset badge: \n\(error)")
        }
        self.handleCallback(error, errorHandler: handleError, completionHandler: {
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber = count
            })
    }
    CKContainer.defaultContainer().addOperation(badgeResetOperation)
}

internal func handleCallback(error: NSError?, errorHandler: ((error: NSError) -> Void)? = nil, completionHandler: () -> Void) {
    if (error != nil) {
        EVLog("Error: \(error?.code) = \(error?.description) \n\(error?.userInfo)")
        if let handler = errorHandler {
            handler(error: error!)
        }
    } else {
        completionHandler()
    }
}
```

The error that I get with this is:

```
04/15/2015 09:12:28:837 AppMessage)[10181:.] EVCloudKitDao.swift(202) handleCallback(_:errorHandler:completionHandler:):
    Error: Optional(4) = Optional("<CKError 0x7fb451c77c10: \"Network Failure\" (4/-1003); \"A server with the specified hostname could not be found.\">") 
Optional([NSErrorFailingURLStringKey: https://ckdevice.icloud.com/api/client/badgeUpdate, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey: 8, NSDebugDescription: NSURLErrorDomain: -1003, NSLocalizedDescription: A server with the specified hostname could not be found., NSErrorFailingURLKey: https://ckdevice.icloud.com/api/client/badgeUpdate, NSUnderlyingError: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1003 "A server with the specified hostname could not be found." UserInfo=0x7fb45351a890 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://ckdevice.icloud.com/api/client/badgeUpdate, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://ckdevice.icloud.com/api/client/badgeUpdate, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=12, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=8, NSLocalizedDescription=A server with the specified hostname could not be found.}, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey: 12])

04/15/2015 09:12:28:839 AppMessage)[10181:.] EVCloudKitDao.swift(788) handleError:
    Error: could not reset badge: 
<CKError 0x7fb451c77c10: "Network Failure" (4/-1003); "A server with the specified hostname could not be found.">
```

A complete functional app with this problem can be found at https://github.com/evermeer/EVCloudKitDao

Comment: It looks like a CloudKit bug. See https://devforums.apple.com/message/1126244#1126244

Comment: i filed a bug report at https://bugreport.apple.com/ with id 20566994

Comment: And i got a reply from an Apple engineer: Duplicate of 20125644 (Open)

Comment: 3 months later and still not working.. :(

Comment: Any fix yet? I just got this same error. Not surprisingly while learning the functions of EVCloudKitDao

Comment: Sad enough it's still failing.

Answer (score 0):

It's an Apple Bug. I use your Apple based API, timeout a user when attempting to log in from a foreign country. Using VPN from US solves the problem, suggesting Cloudkit isn't friendly to non-US territories. Using the API no problem before, it seems this is their latest change.

Specifically, 
CKContainer.fetchUserRecordIDWithCompletionHandler, takes too long or never return.

[Reference from Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/reference/cloudkit/ckcontainer/1399191-fetchuserrecordidwithcompletionh?language=objc)

> At startup time, fetching the user record ID may take longer while
>   CloudKit makes the initial iCloud account request. After the initial
>   fetch, accessing the user record ID should take less time. If no
>   iCloud account is associated with the device, or if access to the
>   user’s iCloud account is restricted, this method returns an error of
>   type CKErrorNotAuthenticated.

@Edwin Vermeer

Please correct me if you have solved it with the updated of your API or Apple fixes it.

Comment: No, I have not changed anything what has to do with the badgecounter. I will try it later to see if it's solved